# IFTTT Service disconnect does not clean up the Oauth Bearer token in my spring security auth server

Tags: spring-security, ifttt

am using spring security. I am able to get the authentication and authorization flow successfully completed using IFTTT. Also the trigger and actions are working and am able to create applet and it works fine. When the Connect Service i.e Oauth flow is completed i see the token generated in my authserver and am able to use that for triggers and actions.

The issue i have is that when i disconnect the Service... the oauth token in the spring security authorization server does not get cleaned up. I also do not see any event being fired by IFTTT to the authorization server to clean up the token.

So how do i clean up the token in the backend when we disconnect the IFTTT Service that we created?

Comment: Similar issue here, have you got a solution to manage service disconnection?